# Ocelot gateway dotnet core running under custom authentication trying to make downstream request with app pool identity

Tags: .net-core, windows-authentication, ocelot

I am running a dotnet 2.2 Ocelot apigateway. What I am trying to achieve is passing a custom api key to the gateway and authorize the token to proceed the request down the chain. This is working fine. However the second piece to this is I'd like for it to run under a windows account application pool identity, and proxy the request into a Windows Authentication protected endpoint. Is this something that is achievable?

My application pool is set on the gateway to a custom domain account, however my requests to the windows authenticated endpoints through the gateway are being rejected with 401 unauthorized. Whereas if i just change the call to a non windows auth protected endpoint the gateway returns the results to me.

Any guidance on this setup of failure points to check or if this is not a feasible approach? I'm hoping the requests would flow as the custom identity account.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        services.AddOcelot();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication().UseOcelot().Wait();          
    }
```

Program.cs

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                      ic => ic.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine("configuration", "configuration.json")))
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

configuration.jcs

```
"ReRoutes": [
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{url}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "somesamplehostname.com",
      "Port": 80
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{url}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
  "AuthenticationOptions": {
    "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Windows"
  }
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Soo here here's what you need to do:

Add The windows auth service: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Set a name identifier to the service you have just initialized by setting DefaultScheme = "≤NAME>";

and set this  to your AuthenticationProviderKey parameter in Ocelot.

It should work like a charm then

Comment: can you show the ConfigureServices and Configure sections of relevant code?  I have been trying:  services
            .AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddNegotiate();      and then  "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Negotiate"

Comment: Cool. Soo it seems fine to me. Here is what you need to do:
Did you try setting the authPersistSingleRequest to True in your services windowsAuth settings?

Setting this flag to true specifies that authentication persists only for a single request on a connection. IIS resets the authentication at the end of each request, and forces reauthentication on the next request of the session.
The default value is false. [1/2]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/#configuration

So it all depends on how connections are being kept open or not between ocelot and the service ( didn't check). If they are kept open and you are on the defaults, then it makes sense that there is no reauth for the second user and setting authPersistSingleRequest would solve that.
Of course it would remove a perf optimization on the other hand. [2/2]

Comment: I do have the authPersistSingleRequest to true on the service. But the Ocelot 
 is returning an error for me on the gateway: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to start Ocelot, errors are: Authentication Options AuthenticationProviderKey:Windows,AllowedScopes:[] is unsupported authentication provider)'

Comment: Authentication Provider Key is the custom name that you give to an identifier, This option is only valid with Identity server  and JWT. You need to remove "AuthenticationOptions": {
    "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Windows"
  }
if you want to go out of the way to use windows authentication.